# Javascript switch case - default option causing error

Tags: javascript

I have code that defines behavior based on which input the code is handeling at that moment.  The code looks something like:

```
switch(inputOption.name) {
 case 'NAME_1':
  switch(inputOption.type.toLowerCase()) {
    case 'radio':
      //some code
    case 'text':
      //some code
    ...
    case 'image':
      //some code

    default:
      return inputOption.value;
      break;
   }
  break;

  default:
    break;
 }
```

The code also includes some cascading cases.  The default option causes the error.  The error is listed as

```
    the default case is already defined
```

What is causing this error?  The error shows up on the package folder, but the file shows no errors in the package view, but it shows errors when I open the file.  I assumed it had something to do with the second default declaration, but it had no effect removing it.

Comment: Which browser is this? Because it's most certainly a bug, the labels should be local to their scope.

Comment: [No you're not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#What_happens_if_I_forgot_a_break).

Comment: Not a browser error, it's showing as an error in eclipse itself.

Comment: Is it an error or a warning? I can understand the second (a missing `break` is *usually* a bug, or at least 'smelly code'), but not an error. That's also why the browsers don't complain.

Comment: It's listed as an error in eclipse.  I'm pretty sure the browser isn't complaining, the submission is working as intended, I just don't understand why eclipse itself is telling me the default case has already been defined.

Comment: Eclipse is a steaming pile of poo. If it's giving bad errors like this, just [disable code inspection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7931839/1729885). And then get a proper IDE like WebStorm of PhpStorm, depending on your main platform.

Comment: It's probably an eclipse bug. However, for clarity, I would break the inner switch into a separate function, then you won't confuse Eclipse. @NielsKeurentjes Eclipse is pretty bad at detecting JS errors. WebStorm is very good at detecting JS errors.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes Hmm...guess that's it then.  I will let me team know.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JuanMendes you're just putting nicely that Eclipse is indeed a steaming pile of poo compared to JetBrains' offerings  ;)

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes Yes, I am forced to use euphemisms to keep others happy. And yes, I am an IntelliJ fan boy

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes Unfortunately, eclipse is the standard where I work, and it's pretty strict at that.  Hopefully saying "big pile of poo" will convince the team to use something else :)

Comment: If nothing else, download a trial. I was forced to use Eclipse until Android SDK support was built into IntelliJ. Downloaded the community edition, uninstalled Eclipse 2 days later, bought cake for the office 2 more days later to celebrate. Crappiest and most unstable unreliable IDE ever.

Comment: @user3334871 See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931089/alternative-to-nested-switch-statements-in-java Many developers try to avoid nested switch statements and switch statements altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You miss break statement for your outer case 'NAME_1'

```
switch(inputOption.name) {
 case 'NAME_1':
  switch(inputOption.type.toLowerCase()) {
    case 'radio':
      //some code
    case 'text':
      //some code
    ...
    case 'image':
      //some code

    default:
      return inputOption.value;
      break;
   }
   break; // <-------------------------------------------------- ADD THIS

  default:
    break;
 }
```

Comment: It may be a solution, but JS most definitely supports fallthrough in switching - his code should be allowed.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to be more clear, there is that line included in the file.  I couldn't directly copy-and-paste, as this is work code.

Comment: @MaksymKozlenko the original code works too, fyi. that's not the point.