# Switch case on object with two instance variables

Tags: java

Is it possible in Java to have a switch-case statement using an object instead of primitive types?

I have a scenario where I have lots of 2d positions (x,y) and I want each of them to behave differently once they're triggered.

So for example, I would like:

```
Pos pos = getNextPos();

switch (pos) {
    case new Pos(1, 2):
        // do something
        break;
    case new Pos(9, 7):
        // do something else...
        break;
    etc...
}
```

or perhaps

```
Pos pos = getNextPos();
Pos[] listOfPos = getListOfPos();

switch (pos) {
    case listOfPos[0]:
        // do something
        break;
    case listOfPos[1]:
        // do something else...
        break;
    etc...
}
```

---

I also implemented the .equals() method in my `Pos` class to return true only if both x and y are equal to the other object.

The `Pos` class (with auto generated equals and hashCode):

```
public class Pos {
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Pos(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Pos pos = (Pos) o;
        return x == pos.x && y == pos.y;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(x, y);
    }
}
```

I've tried all this but when compiling I get "incompatible types: Pos cannot be converted to int".

Comment: You can't do that.  From the [tutorial page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html): "A switch works with the byte, short, char, and int primitive data types. It also works with enumerated types (discussed in Enum Types), the String class, and a few special classes that wrap certain primitive types: Character, Byte, Short, and Integer (discussed in Numbers and Strings)." See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31664071/why-cant-we-switch-on-classes-in-java-7) for more of a discussion about switches in Java.

Answer (score 2):

For the second example,

```
int pos = Arrays.asList(getNextPos()).indexOf(getNextPos());
```

would allow old school `switch`.

It's a dirty, dirty hack, but with switch-on-string, you could:

```
 switch (pos.toString()) {
     case "1,2": ....
```

That does need an appropriate and stable `toString` method, which probably isn't a terrible idea anyway.

Even terribler:

```
 switch (pos.x+","+pos.y) {
     case "1,2": ....
```

Don't try the with user-supplied strings.

There have been noises from Oracle about extending `instanceof` pattern matching (JEP 305) into full on deconstructors for `switch` which could include matching on property values.

Another way around it is to use a `Map` from `Pos` to an appropriate functional type. Perhaps `else`-`if` chains aren't that bad.

Comment: One piece of the pattern matching feature, records, is appearing as a preview feature in JDK 14, but it will probably be a few more versions before pattern matching is ready for use. I've been following the developments a bit, and it looks very interesting. Here's something Brian Goetz and Gavin Bierman wrote about it back in 2018: https://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/amber/pattern-match.html

Answer (score 2):

With Java 8 and lambda, you have ways without the `switch`:

```
class Foobar {
  private final Map<Pos, Consumer<Pos>> mapping;

  Foobar() {
    mapping = new HashMap<>();
    mapping.put(new Pos(1, 2), this::doSomething1);
    mapping.put(new Pos(5, 2), this::doSomething2);
  }

  private void doSomething1(Pos pos) { ... }
  private void doSomething2(Pos pos) { ... }

  public void handleNextPost() {
    Pos pos = getNextPos();
    Consumer<Pos> consumer = mapping.get(getNextPos());
    if (null != consumer) {
      consumer.accept(pos);
    }
  } 
}
```

By the way, at bytecode level, a `switch` on `String` amount to almost the same as a `HashMap`: a `tableswitch` using the `hashCode()` and then as much equals as needed to go to the next statement using `goto`.

The code above is simple:

- I declare a `map` containing for each `Pos` the action you want to do.
- Each action is implemented by a method taking a `Pos`
- When you read `getNextPos()`, you search for the `Consumer` handling said position.
- The `Consumer` is invoked with the `nextPos`.

You may define it locally but you must ensure the `mapping` don't get created each time.

If you really have to stick with `switch`, you don't need anything special: you are using `int` for `Pos x/y` and `switch` naturally work on `int`:

```
switch (pos.getX()) {
  case 0: switch (pos.getY()) {
    case 1: { // [0, 1]
      break;
    }
    case 3: { // [0, 3]
       break;
    }     
  }
  break;
  // ... and so on
}
```

That will easily make your code harder to read, so avoid it.

Also, a `map` is not tailored for loose matching (for example: an action to take for every Pos where x = 1), you may have to use other alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You could go for nested switch-case, but that can be hard to read when trillions of cases arise.

```
Pos pos = new Pos(2,3);

switch(pos.getX()){
    case "2":
        switch(pos.getY()){
            case "3":
                do something with Pos(2,3);
```

Or you could look at this answer with polymorphism [Alternative to Nested Switch Statements in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931089/alternative-to-nested-switch-statements-in-java/15931214) by Nirbhay Mishra.

Comment: I looked at and was interested by the polymorphism answer but don't really know how I would implement it myself, do you know how I could integrate it into my example?

Comment: It appears to me that in this case the polymorphism doesn`t seem to easily work. There are a lot of tutorials out there for replacing switch-cases with polymorphism and at least for my understanding it would be too much of a hassle with 10^2 various combinations.

Answer (score 0):

This somehow resembles the switch statement:

```
    Pos pos = getNextPos();

    Optional.ofNullable(Map.of(new Pos(1, 2), (Runnable) () -> {

        System.out.println(1);

    }, new Pos(3, 2), (Runnable) () -> {

        System.out.println(2);

    }).get(pos)).orElse((Runnable) () -> { // Default

        System.out.println(3);

    }).run();
```

A map of Pos-Objects which map to Runnables.